# IAB (In app billing) in Android : How to give some items for free?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I develop IAB feature in Android application, and I want to offer some items for free. I think there is no way to add product item without price in Google Console.

I think I have to add the free item list and load them manually in app without connecting IAB API. 
I wanna know this process is the best way for offering items for free.

I need your help.

[Edited]

I think there are some way to solve it.

- Retrieving data manually in code.
- Upload free items (with price) in Google console, and display price for 'Free' and then user try to buy it, skip the purchasing process.
- and so on..

What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes google play doesn't support free item

But you can do it with creating a promotion code as a validation that will valid for several time (e.g. 3 days) or count (e.g. 100 first user) and then add the promotion code input inside your app and handle the validation in your server

Comment: Thank your for fast response.
I will offer the items for free without any limits, and the question point is how to retrieving free item list.
I think google console doesn't support free items.

Comment: So I want to know the best practice for that.
It can be fool question but I want to know any other ways for that.

Comment: @FragrantJH I don't think there is another way other than handling it on your own server